# How to synchronize two methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two methods in a Java class that I want to synchronize in the following way: if any of the methods is running, the other must wait until the first finishes in order to start.

This is for the case both methods execution overlap.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: You really should read a concurrency basics tutorial. Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need a common monitor on which to synchronize:

```
private final Object monitor = new Object();

public void methodA() {
  synchronized (monitor) {
    // Do something with exclusive access.
  }
}

public void methodB() {
  synchronized (monitor) {
    // Do something with exclusive access.
  }
}
```

Note that the common monitor can be the instance itself, in which case you can simply add `synchronized` to the method signature:

```
public synchronized void methodA() {
  // Do something with exclusive access.
}
// Same for methodB. No need for `monitor`.
```

Comment: Any known drawback to synchronize itself if locking the entire method is ok?

Comment: You mean to add `synchronized` to the method signature? The main one I can think of is that any other `synchronized` method you add to that class subsequently would also block access to `methodA` and `methodB`.

Answer (score 5):

For two threads with mutual exclusion you can do:

```
private final Object mutex = new Object();

void f() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        ...
    }
}

void g() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Mind if within the synchronized block `f` calls `g` it will not be blocked.
(That would be deadlock anyway.)

You could also make the methods synchronized, without that `mutex`:

```
synchronized void f() { }
synchronized void g() { }
```

which does a synchronized on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways how to do that:
-  first way is to use  [monitors](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-5-monitors-locks-and-conditions.html)- or [sempahores](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/08/java-concurrency-part-4-semaphores.html). It's useful for exclusive access, called critical section (eg. shared resources, etc., synchronization), "mutex way"

Second, the most simply is probably to use `notify()` and `wait()`- (without objects above, just using `synchronize`)- for [this look there](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/)
More about monitors and using you can [read there](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-5-monitors-locks-and-conditions.html)